# how to choose what to print from Mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have file to print orders from table in database, but I want to choose row with same value entered by the user
here is my PHP file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function printpage()  {  window.print()}</script>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM order_items");

 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
<th>ANAME</th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>QUANTITY</th>
<th> PRICE</th>
<th>CUSTOMER</th>
<th>DATETIME</th>
<th>TOATAL COAST</th>
<th>TOTAL WIGHT</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

 echo "<td>" . $row['aname'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['id']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['name']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['quantity'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['price'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['customer'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['datetime'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['totalcost'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['totalweight'] ."</td>";   


echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Print this page\" onclick=\"printpage()\" />";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

now I want to retrieve only records where customer is "specific customer" to print them

Comment: add `WHERE where customer="specific customer"` to your query.

Comment: ok, Thanks Michel but that is if I want to always print that customer order. I need a way to choose which customer I want to print

Comment: Thanks I solved by using the form